# How to enable debug mode for firebase analytics events in Unity android project?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, debugging, firebase-analytics

In firebase documentation, only this paragraph describes how to turn on debug mode for events,

> "To enable Analytics Debug mode on an Android device, execute the following commands:
>   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app package_name"

however, I think that you can do it only in android studio.

How to turn on debug mode for firebase events in my Unity project?

Comment: You actually run this command from the command line after [installing the Android SDK](https://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/Manual/android-sdksetup.html).

Comment: Oooh, when I test it on a plugged-in device or an emulator? Thank you!

Comment: Following up on @FrankvanPuffelen's comment, newer versions of Unity optionally install their own Android SDK. In this case, the path to ADB is {Unity_Installation_Directory}/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools/adb

I use Unity Hub and currently have 2019.2.3f1 installed. So the command without messing with my path or cd'ing to a weird directory would be:
/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.3f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools/adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app package_name

Comment: It should work with a device or emulator. If you have a device plugged in and an emulator running, you would have to add an extra flag to select the device to execute the shell command in.

Comment: Sounds like you have enough for an answer there @Pux0r3! :-D

Answer (score 1):

To wrap this all up in an answer. Using the Firebase SDK, you can execute `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app package_name` to enable debug mode. Adb is a the "Android Debug Bridge", which exists on your machine if you're able to load games onto a phone (either via Android Studio or via Unity).

For finding your SDK location and setting your path, it depends on the host OS and shell you're running as well as how you've installed the Android SDK. Therefore, I'll try to give OS agnostic instructions for if you selected to install the Android SDK that ships in Unity 2019 (specifically 2019.2.3f1 as installed by Unity Hub).

In this case, the path to ADB is `{Unity_Installation_Directory}/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools/adb`. So the command without messing with my path or cd'ing to a weird directory would be: `/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.3f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/SDK/platform-tools/adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app package_name`

Now, I have Android Studio installed and I use my `.profile` file to set my path on OSX (I use the fish shell, so this is a little tricky). To make that version of ADB accessible as a command as indicated by the instructions page, I have this towards the end of the file:

```
# Add environment variable NDK_ROOT
export NDK_ROOT="/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH=$NDK_ROOT:$PATH
```

But this is specific enough that I posted the general solution first.

Hope this helps!

--Patrick